# how does parallel GADriver support distributed memory

Tags: openmdao

When I set run_parallel = True for the SimpleGADriver how is the memory handled? Does it do anything with the distributed memory? Does it send each point in generation to a single memory (in case I have a setup that connects multiple nodes (each has its own memory) ) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I completely understand your question, but I can give an overview of how it works.

When "run_parallel" is True, and you are running under MPI with `n` processors, the SimpleGADriver will use those procs to evaluate the newly generated population design values. To start, the GA runs on each processor with local values in local memory. When a new set of points is generated, the values from rank 0 are broadcast to all ranks and placed into a list. Then those points are evaluated based on the processor rank, so that each proc is evaluating a different point. When completed, all of the values are allgathered, after which, every processor has all of the objective values for the new generation. This process continues until termination criteria are reached.

So essentially, we are just using multiple processors to speed up objective function evaluation (i.e., running the model), which can be significant for slower models.

One caveat is that the total population size needs to be divisible by the number of processors or an exception will be raised.

The choice to broadcast the population from rank 0 (rather than any other rank) is arbitrary, but those values come from a process that includes random crossover and tournament selection, so each processor does generate a new valid unique population and we just choose one.